Werner Greub's formulation of the Universal Property of the Tensor Product
$\def\id{\operatorname{id}}$
$\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}}
$In Section 1.4 of  Multilinear Algebra Werner Greub starts with a bilinear map $\otimes: E \times F \rightarrow T$ where $E,F,T$ are vector spaces, and defines the universal property of $\otimes$ as,

$\Im \otimes = T$.
If $\phi$ is a bilinear mapping from $E \times F$ into any vector space $H$ then there exists a linear map $f:T \rightarrow H$ such that the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd} 
\begin{CD}
E \times F @>{\phi}>> H \\
@V{\otimes}VV {_{}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(-30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{2.2em}{0em}]{}}}_f} \\
T 
\end{CD}
$$
commutes.

Then he asserts that these two conditions are equivalent to the single condition that for every bilinear mapping from $\phi: E \times F \rightarrow H$ there exists a unique linear map $f:T \rightarrow H$ such that
$\phi(x,y)=f(x \otimes y)$.
To prove this equivalence he assumes that there exist two linear maps $f_1: T \rightarrow H$ and $f_2: T \rightarrow H$ with this property. For any $x \in E, y \in F$, $\phi(x,y)=f_1(x\otimes y)$ and $\phi(x,y)=f_2(x \otimes y)$. The author then asserts that since $\Im \otimes = T$ it follows that $f_1=f_2$.
Question: Assume that $\Im \otimes \subset T$ ($\otimes$ does not generate $T$; it is merely a subset of $T$). We have two linear maps $f_1,f_2$ such that for any $x \in E, y \in F$ take $x \otimes y \in T$ and map it to exactly the same vector $\phi(x,y) \in H$. Even though $\otimes$ does not generate $T$ isn't it the case that two maps with this property are equal?
I have looked at the list of similar questions but cannot get any light.

"isn't it the case that two maps with this property are equivalent?": you mean equal ( "equivalent" means nothing). Well no, it is not the case. Take for instance $T=(E\otimes F)\oplus k$ where $k$ is the field of scalars, and $\forall z\in E\otimes F,\forall\lambda\in k,f_2(z,\lambda)=f_1(z,\lambda)+\lambda$. Then, $f_1,f_2$ coincide on $E\otimes F$ (i.e. $f_1(z,0)=f_2(z,0)$) but $f_1\ne f_2$.

@AnneBauval adding the direct sum is a bit confusing.  If we forget about tensor products, we have a map $\pi: E \times F \rightarrow T$ and a map $\phi: E \times F \rightarrow H$. $f_1(\pi(x,y))=f_2(\pi(x,y))$ for all $x \in E, y \in F$. Then $f_1=f_2$ even if $\pi$ does not generate $T$.

No, again, $f_1\ne f_2$ (and my counterexample should make it clear) $f_1,f_2$ coincide only on the subspace ${\rm im}(\pi)$ of $T$.

@TedBlack This issue doesn't really have anything to do with bilinear maps or tensor products. If two linear maps $f_1,f_2:V\to W$ agree on a proper subspace of $V$, it need not be the case that $f_1=f_2$, because $f_1$ and $f_2$ may disagree on the other stuff in $V$.

@blargoner thanks that's a good point. We could have $f_1 \neq f_2$ and still have $f_1=f_2$ in some subset of $V$. Only if they agree in their domain, $V$, we can say $f_1=f_2$.

@blargoner apologies for contacting you through a comment You have a great github page ( https://github.com/blargoner/math-algebra-greub ) where not only you provide comments and solutions for both Linear Algebra and Multilinear Algebra by Werner Greub but also a long list of errata! For those of us who are not as confident in handling these great books is there a more recent substitute (at the graduate level)?
